# Does the nerve of a category preserve directed colimits?

Tags: category-theory

The [nerve](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve) $N(C)$ of a category $C$ is a simplicial set and defines a functor
$$
N\colon\operatorname{Categories}\to \operatorname{sSets}
$$
from the category of small categories to simplcial sets.
 It is given by $N(C)_n=\operatorname{Hom_{Categories}}(\Delta[n],C)$ and $\Delta[n]$ is the obvious category.

> Does $N$ preserve directed colimits?

This is true if $\Delta[n]$ is a [compact](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+finitely+presentable+category) object in $\operatorname{Categories}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $\Delta[n]$ is compact: it has finitely many objects and morphisms!

Comment: (However, not every compact category is finite.)

Comment: (That is correct, @ZhenLin, for example, the one-object category $B\mathbb{N}$ is compact. The parenthesis around these comments make it feel like we're whispering...)